# In an expression tree, how do I use an expression that requires a comparison to be made with the result, eg. IndexOf?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I know how to do this:

```
    Expression body = Expression.Call(selector.Body, "Contains", null,
        Expression.Constant("cats", typeof(string)));
```

Since 'contains' returns true/false it's no problem.

However, how do I do IndexOf and see if the result is greater than 5?

```
    Expression body = Expression.Call(selector.Body, "IndexOf", null,
        Expression.Constant("cats", typeof(string)));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [`Expression.GreaterThan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356438.aspx):

```
Expression body = 
 Expression.GreaterThan(
   Expression.Call(selector.Body, "IndexOf", null, Expression.Constant("cats")),
   Expression.Constant(5)
 );
```